# Interface as a type in Java?

Tags: java, interface

From [The Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html):

> In Java, a class can inherit from only one class but it can implement
>   more than one interface. Therefore, **objects can have multiple types**:
>   the type of their own class and the types of all the interfaces that
>   they implement. This means that if a **variable is declared to be the
>   type of an interface, its value can reference any object that is
>   instantiated from any class that implements the interface**.

Can anyone provide me a basic pseudo type for this. I did not understand the bold lines.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Let's declare two interfaces and a class that implements them both:

```
interface I1 { }

interface I2 { }

class C implements I1, I2 { }
```

> **objects can have multiple types**

In the following code, it can be seen that a `C` instance has the type of `C` as well as `I1` and `I2`:

```
C c = new C();

boolean isC = (c instanceof C);   //true
boolean isI1 = (c instanceof I1); //true
boolean isI2 = (c instanceof I2); //true
```

Now let's declare a class `B` which implements `I1` as well:

```
class B implements I1 { }
```

> **if a variable is declared to be the type of an interface, its value can reference any object that is instantiated from any class that implements the interface.**

If we declare a variable of type `I1`, we can set it to an instance of `C`, and then reassign it to an instance of `B`:

```
I1 i1 = new C();
i1 = new B();
```

We can also reassign it to an instance of `D`, where `D` extends `C`:

```
i1 = new D();

...

class D extends C { }
```

Answer (score 16):

Consider the following example:

```
Serializable s = new ArrayList();
```

In Java, this is valid code, even though `Serializable` is an interface, because `ArrayList` implements `Serializable`.  So in this case, we're treating `s` as a variable of type `Serializable`.

Now suppose we follow up the above code with the following:

```
s = "String object";
```

This is also valid because`String` also implements `Serializable`.  Since we declared `s` as type `Serializable`, it can point to *any* object that implements that interface.

Answer (score 7):

**objects can have multiple types**

Consider the following snippet:

```
public class MyClass extends ParentClass implements Interface1, Interface2 {    
    //some code    
}
```

This class can be used in different places as follows:

```
MyClass m1 = new MyClass();
ParentClass p = new MyClass();
Interface1 i1 = new MyClass();
Interface2 i2 = new MyClass();
```

**variable is declared to be the type of an interface, its value can reference any object that is instantiated from any class that implements the interface.**

Consider the last two lines in the previous snippet, a variable of type Interface1 can reference any object that implements this interface, so if we have another class implements Interface1, say MyClass2, then

```
Interface1 i1 = new MyClass();
Interface1 i2 = new MyClasss2();
i1 = i2;
i1 = new MyClass2();
```

All the previous assignments are valid because MyClass and MyClass2 implements Interface1

Answer (score 6):

```
class Ball extends Rubber implements Jumping, Rolling, Squeezing {
   public void jump(){}
   public void roll(){}
   public void squeeze(){}
}

Ball b = new Ball();
Jumping j = new Ball();
j.jump();

//j.roll();         //CTE: Cannot resolve method roll()
((Ball) j).roll();  //but it still can be called if explicit cast to type Ball is used
```

Answer (score 3):

`String` implements multiple interfaces, so it has multiple types:

```
String s = "A String";
Comparable<String> comp = s;
CharSequece cs = s;
Serializable ser = s;
```

The interface `CharSequence` is implemented by multiple classes, so a `CharSequence` reference can hold all kinds of objects:

```
CharSequence cs = "A String";
cs = new StringBuilder();
cs = new Segment();
```

Answer (score 3):

> objects can have multiple types

Example:

```
public class Foo implements Runnable, Callable<Integer> {
  public void run() {}
  public Integer call() {return 1;}
}

Foo foo = new Foo();
Runnable r = foo;
Callable<Integer> c = foo;
```

Example:

> if a variable is declared to be the type of an interface, its value can reference any object that is instantiated from any class that implements the interface

```
Runnable r = new Foo();
r = Thread.currentThread();   //Thread implements Runnable
```

Answer (score 2):

The statements you quote (from where?) are true but misleading -- objects already have multiple types without interfaces.

For example, `"bimmelim"` has the type `String`, but it also has the type `Object`. Interfaces do not change that, except that `"bimmelim"` *also* has the type `Serializable`, `CharSequence` and others.

Actually, it is possibly debatable whether we should say that `"bimmelim"` *"has"* the type `Object`, but certainly a reference to it will fit into an `Object` variables.

If a variable is declared to be type of an interface ... for example

```
CharSequence x ;
```

... then its value can reference a `String` object such as `"bimmelim"`, or it could possibly be a `StringBuffer`, which is another type that implements `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 2):

That the following is a correct assignment:

```
class AClass implements AInterface {
}


AInterface var = new AClass();
```

Answer (score 2):

Very basic example-

```java
List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Since, `ArrayList` implements List therefore we can use List interface variable i.e list1 to refer to the object created by `Arraylist`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following class and interface definitions:

```
public class A { }

public class B extends A implements I { }

public interface I { }
```

The following statements are all legal:

```
A first = new A();
B second = new B();
A third = new B();
I fourth = new B();
```

Because B implements I and extends A, it can be used as a value anywhere an "I" or an "A" is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Take the [`Collection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface from the standard Java libraries as an example. Any variable declared as of type `Collection` can then be assigned an object of a class which implements the `Collection` interface, e.g. `ArrayList`, `Stack`, ... see the linked doc for more examples.