# What kind of casting is this? (from Y to X)

Tags: java

```
public class X{
    public void move(){}
}

public interface Y{
    abstract void move();
}
public class A extends X implements Y{

}

//in the main function
public static void main(String[] args){
    Y eg=new A(); //line 1
    X eg2=(X)eg; //line 2
}
```

What kind of casting would this be from interface Y to class X? Is it a downcasting or upcasting or neither of both?

If it is a upcasting, why do we need an explicit cast in line 2? I tried without an explicit cast and an error was thrown.

Comment: You are casting an instance of `A` to `X`. `A` is a subclass of `X`, so it would usually be considered **upcasting**. Not that it really matters though, those terms are not official - check the JLS for precise terminology.

Comment: Seems like the JLS terminoligy is widening (casting to a superclass) and narrowing (casting to a subclass). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/jls13.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Line `Y eg=new A();` does not make the instance to be of type Y. **It's always instance of A.** You are just assigning it to be referenced by type Y, Y being a super type.

Then in `X eg2=(X)eg;` you are casting type A to type X & NOT Y to X. This is clearly upcasting.

The **explicit casting is needed to remove ambiguity** because X & Y are at same level and instance of A can be referenced by both X & Y type.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275844/interface-as-a-type-in-java) link may be helpful.

Comment: shouldn't it be casting from Y to X since in line Y, the reference type is Y. Otherwise downcasting is never possible if all castings is with respect to object type.

Comment: @Zen12345 downcasting is also done on object type. Ex: Car c = new Car();  BMW b = (BMW) c;   b.methodOnlyInBMW(); This code will compile without error but it'll throw ClassCastException. Better way of writing would be:                                                Car c = new Car();                                                                                                          if(c instanceof BMW) {
            BMW b = (BMW) c;
            b.methodOnlyInBMW();
        }     // Look the use of "instanceof" here. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have name, as far as I know.
It is generally unsafe, and makes no sense.

Your inheritance tree is below, `X` and `Y` are not related with each other. Your attempt will be a result in `ClassCastException` which occurs an invalid cast.
Object (more accurately, `java.lang.Object`) is the top of inheritance tree. since `X` and `Y` does not `extends` anything, they inherit from Object implicitly.

```
Object
 / \
X   Y
 \ /
  A
```

Comment: Well no, in this case A implements both X and Y. It is legal to cast an instance of A to X and then to Y or vice versa.

Comment: Its a valid cast & it does not result in ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an upcasting too.

You have X that's is a regular class with move() method.
You have Y that's is an abstract class, thus cannot be instantiated.
You have A class that extends from X, then it inherit the X method. With this, from A you inherit the move() method from X class. You can add "implements Y" to say that you need to code your move function() but this has no real effect since the A class already has the move() method.

In the code in main you are:

Y eg=new A();

You create an A class and assign it to an Y variable. You can do. What you clearly couldn't do it's Y eg = new Y(); since Y cannot be instantiated.
This Y knows it has the move() method, but doesn't know it's implementation. Since A has the implementation, you could do this and do Y.move() without issue.

X eg2=(X)eg;

In this case is an upcasting from A->X, since A is the child of X. Upcasting by definition is the typecasting of a child object to a parent object.

Hope you find this useful.

Regards.

Comment: i agree it might be upcasting but isnt upcasting able to be done implicitly? I tried doing without the (X) in line 2 and I got a compilation error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Y to X. So i am not too sure...